# Derivation in joint probability

Tags: probability

If $A,B,C$ are events in a sample space $S$.

Assume that $A,B$ are independent events in S.

then

$P(AB|C)=P(A|C) \cdot P(B|C)$

Is it correct ? if correct then how to prove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Build a counterexample as follows. We toss a fair coin twice. Let $A$ be the event we get a head on the first toss, and $B$ the event we get a head on the second toss. Let $C$ be the event that the total number of heads is odd.